# How to call an event from another class in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to call a mouse click event in QWebview to get a text by copy in the QWebView page but I don't know how. I have been trying to solve this for sometimes now.

Here is the minor code

```
    import sys
    
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    from PyQt5 import Qt
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import *
    
           
    class sw(QWebView):
       def keyPressEvent(self, e):
           clipboard=QApplication.clipboard()
           data=clipboard.mimeData()
           print(data.text)
           super(Mainw, self).keyPressEvent(e)
    
            
    
    class Mainw(QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            
            #QTextEdit().__init__()
            self.m=QMenuBar(self)
            self.file=self.m.addMenu("file")
            self.new=QAction("new", self)
            self.file.addAction(self.new)
            
            
            ed=QWebView(self)
            ed.setHtml(imported_data)
            
            ed.setGeometry(20,30,400,400)
    
    if __name__=="__main__":
                a=QApplication(sys.argv)
                app=Mainw()
                #sb=app.open()
                
                app.show()
                sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

I know there are alot or errors in this code

Comment: Please improve your indentation. What version of pyqt5 do you use? I ask because QWebView is no longer available in the current versions besides that I do not see any "import" that imports that class-

Comment: Also, the `sw` class is declared but never actually used...

Comment: Yeah sir, I have edited the code and has imported QWebKitWdigets which the module for qwebview.

Comment: Am using pyqt5 version 5.15.. I don't really know how to call a signal or event from another class. That Is why I asked. I need a code that will help me understand how to call these events. I tried the documentations but don't really understand.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by calling the KeyPressEvent in the other widget?

Comment: Actually my main aim is to be able to get text from a qwebview page using events, so I was trying different event types mouse and keyboard. But I realized I don't even know to call a pyqt event

Comment: Events are rarely called manually. To send information between widgets you would normally use signals and slots.

Comment: OK thanks  Heike, but there is no signal associated with clipboard copy triggers in QWebview..is there anyway I can do about it.?

Comment: You can create your own signal and emit that whenever you copy data to the clipboard. Then in Mainw you would connect an appropriate slot to the signal.

Comment: @welmanebimobowei Your question is unclear, could you explain your underlying objective instead of the possible solution. Please use `@username`

Comment: @Heike, thanks for your concern, now I understand better. Could you show me a working example on how to create signals so I can try with that.